# Generate Scala case class with scrooge

Tags: scala, thrift, scrooge

I am trying to generate scala a Case Class from a .thrift file but scrooge will generate for my example an object + trait from a struct like below:

Do you know whether it's possible to generate directly a case class using scrooge?

```
namespace java com.twitter.demo
#@namespace scala com.twitter.demo.thriftscala

struct User {
  1: i64 id
  2: string name
  3: string job
}
```

will generate:

```
object User extends ThriftStructCodec3[User] { ...

trait User extends ThriftStruct..
```

thanks

Comment: scrooge doesn't generate case classes. There is a (regular) class `User.Immutable` that you can use (not directly, but by calling `User.apply`). Why do you need a case class?